# Create Columns from Column Unique Values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to Python and was hoping someone might be able to give me some tips.  I'm  also new to posting on stack over flow, so any tips on how to display a table in it would definitely be appreciated as well.

Anyways, I have two columns D and J as pictured in the before area below.  I would like to create a new table as shown in the after area below where I create columns from the unique values in the J column and add a 1 in each row to indicate the record had the unique value.  Someone suggested get_dummies from the pandas library.  I'm working in the pandas library, but again I'm very new.  Thanks again for any advice.

Before:

```
D | J

A | 1q

B | 2E

C | 7F
```

After:

```
D | 1q |2E | 7F

A | 1 |

B | .. | 1

C | .. | .. | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [45]: pd.get_dummies(df['J'])
Out[45]: 
   1q  2E  7F
D            
A   1   0   0
B   0   1   0
C   0   0   1
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for getting back to me on this.  I tried your suggestion but I'm not getting the values from column D as an index.  Instead I get 0 1 2.  I read the table in from a csv file using test = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\t_shies\\Documents\\James Project\\Partner Expertise\\Test.csv')  and then ran pd.get_dummies(test['J'])
Sorry for the lousy formatted response, I haven't figured out how to post things nicely yet.

Comment: this is with 0.13.1, IIRC their were some changes recently. what version pandas? you can always ``x = pd.get_dummies(df['J']); x.index = df.index`` as well

Comment: Hi Jeff, I was able to solve my problem with df = df.set_index('D')

Answer (score 0):

It works, but not really straightforward

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'D': ['A',  'B',  'C'] ,'J':['1q',  '2E', '7F']})
df = df.set_index('D')

uniqueJ = df['J'].unique()
res=pd.concat([df['J']==v for v in uniqueJ],axis=1)
res.columns=uniqueJ
res=res.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
```